# Azure ACR login using golang sdk

Tags: azure, go, sdk, azure-acr

I'm looking for a way to get Azure ACR access token using golang sdk.
Similar to the result of the following console commands:

```
az login --service-principal -u <app-id> -p <password-or-cert> --tenant <tenant>
az acr login --name <registry id> --expose-token --only-show-errors
```

Comment: Have you looked at the docs from Microsoft? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/go/azure-sdk-authorization

Comment: sure, but unfortunately still cannot make it work :(

Comment: You can refer to [Suggestion: Azure Container registry Repository Client unable to fetch attributes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/issues/8654#issuecomment-628977113). You can also open an issue on GitHub: [azure-sdk-for-go](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/issues)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Just set `tenantId` and `acrService` and run it. The output will give you user and password (token) to use in a docker login command. Please note: User is literally "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000". Don't replace that.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"

    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azcore/policy"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azidentity"
)

func main() {
    tenantId := "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    acrService := "crmichitest.azurecr.io"
    cred, err := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    ctx := context.Background()
    aadToken, err := cred.GetToken(ctx, policy.TokenRequestOptions{Scopes: []string{"https://management.azure.com/.default"}})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    formData := url.Values{
        "grant_type":   {"access_token"},
        "service":      {acrService},
        "tenant":       {tenantId},
        "access_token": {aadToken.Token},
    }
    jsonResponse, err := http.PostForm(fmt.Sprintf("https://%s/oauth2/exchange", acrService), formData)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var response map[string]interface{}
    json.NewDecoder(jsonResponse.Body).Decode(&response)
    fmt.Println("User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
    fmt.Println("Token:", response["refresh_token"])
}
```

Then, just log into the registry:

```
docker login -u "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" -p "<TOKEN FROM OUTPUT>" crmichitest.azurecr.io
```